# Warning of deleting question with answer after deleting the answer

Tags: discussion, support

I've posted a question earlier and answered it later after finding the solution. But then I thought it's not really a helpful question for others, so I decided to delete it.

I know it's not good to delete questions with answers, so I deleted the answer first and then tried to delete the question.

But it still gives me the warning, not to delete questions which have an answer!

First of all, I answered the question myself.

Secondly, I've deleted the answer.

So why does it still warn me not to delete [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376975/cannot-resolve-symbol-rtlunderlay-widget-appcompat-actionbutton) which has no answer?

Comment: The OP *did* delete the answer, just check the [post history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35377240/revisions). Presumably the OP undeleted the answer only after finding out that deleting the question didn't work.

Comment: "I know it's not good to delete questions with answers, so I deleted the answer first and then tried to delete the question." You are still deleting a question with an answer, I can't see how deleting the answer first make it better.

Comment: I DID delete the answer. as @hvd mentioned, I've undeleted the answer cause it didn't work and no one answered the question here

Comment: So are you saying that is not just an ignorable warning (as Servy assumes) but an outright block on deletion?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm saying I'll get suspended if I delete some questions with answers and if it warns me about deleting this, then it will count it as one of my few attempts to deleting a question with answer, while it really doesn't have one!

Comment: Sounds like something you can just ignore as long as you don't make a habit of it.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like a bug to me.

Deleted answers obviously should not count towards the "this question has answers so you <strike>can't</strike> are encouraged not to delete it" logic.

It doesn't matter that 10k+ users can still see deleted posts.

Comment: The point of the logic is that an answer may be helpful and will be lost if the question is deleted. Even a deleted answer (that was deleted minutes ago) may be erroneously deleted, that's why undeletion exists. So to me it makes sense to at least have a period between answer and question deletion.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: I dunno, maybe; I can see where you're coming from but I think the odds of us needing complex rules in place to guard against someone deleting the question during the few seconds it takes someone to realise they just accidentally deleted their answer ... are pretty low. Gotta draw the line somewhere.

Comment: The OP *isn't* being prevented from deleting the post.  He's being warned that it's answered, and that he's deleting a post with an answer.  He can still delete it if he want to ignore the warning.

Comment: @Servy Okay. Still.

Comment: I cleaned up the comments on both the answers here. If you wish to carry on this conversation, I recommend taking it to chat.

Answer (score -14):

> First of all, I answered the question myself.

Why is this relevant?

> Secondly, I've deleted the answer.

And yet the question still has an answer.  Such is the consequence of soft deletes, rather than hard deletes.

---

If you *really* feel that the question or answer isn't going to be of any value to anyone else, you can delete it.  It is after all just a warning that the behavior might be harmful, not that it's prohibited.  If, based on the reflection you've done since seeing the warning, you think that this post could plausibly be helpful to others, then the fact that you've chosen not to delete it means that the warning did its job.

Comment: The fact that he answered the question himself is plainly relevant -- if there are no other answers, you'd expect to be able to delete your own answer, then delete your own question.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty And he can.  Nothing is stopping him from doing that.  He's just being warned that he's deleting an answered question, and that he should be sure that he's okay with doing that.  If he's confident that the answer has no value, then he can delete the question, just like I said in the answer here.  Did you not read the second half of my answer?

Comment: That "why is this relevant" bit seems to be a lure for quick downvotes that this answer really does not deserve. Perhaps remove it, if you care.

Comment: @Gimby: If this is a bug (which it may or may not be), having more info is always helpful to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MageXy This isn't a bug.  There isn't anything stopping him from deleting the question.  There's just a warning that can be ignored.  That warning is entirely appropriate here.

Comment: @Servy: No, it's not "entirely appropriate here". The answer was deleted. Gone. Kaput. Its prior existence should have no bearing or relevance on _anything_ any more, be that on a block from question deletion or merely a warning suggesting to the question author that they may not wish to delete it. I find it hard to believe that this could possibly be expected behaviour.

Comment: @PreferenceBean The OP was trying to delete an answered question, and he was warned that he should be careful when deleting answered questions because others might find them useful.  Sounds like the system is doing *exactly* what it should be doing.  And no ,deleting answers *doesn't* just erase them; answer are soft deleted; they're not just gone.